# Filter a dataframe by different timestamp formats

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe with a stime stamp feature that has two different formats, for example

```
created                     name
2020-04-30T20:06:00.000Z    Back
--T::00.000Z                Summary
2020-04-30T20:05:00.000Z    Recalculate
2020-04-30T20:05:00.000Z    Recalculate
--T::00.000Z                Recalculate
```

I would like to filter this dataframe in order to get only good formatted timestamps 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.000Z', i.e. to get the dataframe

```
created                     name
2020-04-30T20:06:00.000Z    Back
2020-04-30T20:05:00.000Z    Recalculate
2020-04-30T20:05:00.000Z    Recalculate
```

How to filter by time stamp format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with optional parameter `errors=coerce` to convert `created` column to a series of pandas datetime then use [`Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) to create a boolean mask and use this mask to filter the dataframe:

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df['created'], errors='coerce').notna()
df = df[m]
```

---

```
# print(df)
                    created         name
0  2020-04-30T20:06:00.000Z         Back
2  2020-04-30T20:05:00.000Z  Recalculate
3  2020-04-30T20:05:00.000Z  Recalculate
```